# Display inline error message with new line

Tags: html, angular, dom

I'm trying to display inline error message

My goal is to achieve this:

Error 1

Error 2

but instead it appears in the same line like : Error 1 Error 2

I tried using document.createElement("br") but no use.

Below is my code:

HTML:

```
  <span *ngIf="ifError()"class="validation_class">
  <p id="inline_error">{{inlineErrorMsgs}}</p></span>
```

TS:

```
 ifError(){
 var Errormsg:string;
 var br = document.createElement("br");
 for(var i=0;i<this.messages.length;i++){
 Errormsg = this.messages[i]
 this.inlineErrorMsgs = this.inlineErrorMsgs+Errormsg+br;
 }
```

How can I add new line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="errorMessages && errorMessages.length > 0">
<div *ngFor="let d of errorMessages">
<p>
 {{d}}
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

TS

```
export class ComponentA {
errorMessages : [] = [];

someMethod(){
this.messages.forEach((j) => {
// here you can add some logic if you want.
errorMessages.push(j);
})
}
```

please don't use document object directly or I would say try to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you , it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Store error messages in array and display them using ng-for loop